# Migrating BLOB in Oracle into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle, migration, postgresql-9.4, blob

I use the data type `BLOB` in an Oracle table to store images and document files.  Now for Postgres(9.4.5), I have two options, i.e., `BYTEA` or `OID`.

With consideration of passing the params (SAVING) from the Java side as follows:

```
DiskFileItemDeepy file  =  myFile;  
InputStream is = null;
long fileSize = 0;
if (file != null && file.getFileSize() > 0){ 
  is = file.getInputStream(); 
  fileSize = file.getFileSize(); 
  call.setBinaryStream(1, (InputStream)is,  (long)fileSize);
}
...
call.execute(); 

//When retrieve the data use:

java.sql.Blob blob = (Blob) resultSet.getBlob(tableColumnName);
```

For the purpose mentioned above, which Postgres data type is a better candidate for replacement of the `BLOB`, is it `BYTEA` or `OID`?

Comment: You don't have two options. `OID` is not a user data type. Besides, since it is [implemented as a 32-bit integer](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-oid.html), there aren't many images and documents you'll be able to store as `OID`.

Comment: @mustaccio: the `OID` part refers to using "large objects". The actual value is not stored in that column. The column simply links to data stored in `pg_largeobject`

Answer (score 7):

From a conceptual point of view the equivalent to Oracle's `BLOB` datatype is `bytea` in Postgres.

`bytea` only allows you to read and write the *complete* data (you can't just retrieve 100KB from a 1GB value). Which means that this is kept in the memory on the JVM while reading it. This is the same as with Oracle's `BLOB` type. From a JDBC point of view those two data types behave nearly the same.

The OID (or better: "large objects") isn't a real "data type". It is merely a pointer to the data stored in the file system. The advantage of using large objects is that you can properly stream the content from the server to the client, you don't need to load the entire binary data into the client's memory.

However dealing with large objects is much more complicated than dealing with `bytea` columns. You also need to *manually* clean up deleted large objects if you delete the corresponding row from the base table (something you do not need to do with `bytea`). Reading and writing of large objects is also much more complicated then dealing with `bytea` values.

As you are currently using a `BLOB` column, you apparently do have the memory on the client side to process the data, in that case to make transition as smooth as possible, I highly recommend to use `bytea` in Postgres.